# Build Upload using Artifactory REST API

Tags: powershell, rest, artifactory

I am having trouble figuring out how to register an already uploaded artifact to the artifactory build. I know that I can use the artifactory build upload endpoint which is partly working for me but just can't figure out the correct payload to use for the JSON data.

I have tried using different payload referring to the information I see under the artifact information.

This is my payload:

```
{
    "url":  "https://bamboo-ci-server-url/browse/EC-SRT0-25",
    "vcsRevision":  "14fc6dcf71bee74e328078",
    "artifactoryPrincipal":  "username",
    "version":  "4.0.0-SNAPSHOT",
    "number":  "27",
    "started":  "2019-11-04T19:49:35.471+0100",
    "name":  "SPO3.MGUI.RTEST",
    "properties":  {
                       "buildInfo.env.JAVA_HOME":  "java_home"
                   },
    "issues":  {
                   "tracker":  {
                                   "version":  "8.5.0",
                                   "name":  "JIRA"
                               },
                   "affectedIssues":  [
                                          {
                                              "url":  "https://jira-url/browse/projectkey-3433",
                                              "key":  "projectkey-3433",
                                              "summary":  "Testing snapshot builds automation"
                                          },
                                          {
                                              "url":  "https://bamboo-ci-cerver-url/browse/EC-3408",
                                              "key":  "projectkey-3408",
                                              "summary":  "Create release for 1.4"
                                          }
                                      ]
               },
    "modules":  [
                    {
                        "id":  "SPO3.MGUI.RTEST-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT",
                        "artifacts":  [
                                          {
                                              "name":  "/com/company/module/SPO3.MGUI.RTEST/4.0.0-SNAPSHOT/ivy.xml",
                                              "md5":  "a242c427c6c1fdcd33c1c0498fb41324",
                                              "type":  "application/xml",
                                              "sha1":  "2d4916b9a1292dca8875b1aceaca9beb8de1a5e6"
                                          },
                                          {
                                              "name":  "/com/company/module/SPO3.MGUI.RTEST/4.0.0-SNAPSHOT/SPO3.MGUI.RTEST-bin-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip",
                                              "md5":  "581be6dd9e6615d14db2bb0d05c724e6",
                                              "type":  "application/x-gzip",
                                              "sha1":  "62436ab1aff6cdcdeba59bcac39d6223697398c4"
                                          }
                                      ]
                    }
                ],
    "vcsUrl":  "https://bitbucket-url/project/ec/repo.git"
}
```

I submit it like this:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method PUT -Body $json -ContentType 'application/json' -Headers $headers
To the URL - https://artifactory-url/artifactory/api/build
```

I expect that successful build upload would link my artifact to the build so that I can directly see the artifact from the build info page.

I think my payload information is incorrect but I just can't figure out what I should use.

This is what I see under my artifact build information:

```
Name:   ivy.xml
Repository Path:    repo-snapshot-local/com/company/module/SPO3.MGUI.RTEST/4.0.0-SNAPSHOT/ivy.xml
Module ID:  com.company.module:SPO3.MGUI.RTEST:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

To be specific and if I am correct, this is where I need help (to put correct artifact information to be used for the module id, name, etc:

```
"modules":  [
                    {
                        "id":  "SPO3.MGUI.RTEST-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT",
                        "artifacts":  [
                                          {
                                              "name":  "/com/company/module/SPO3.MGUI.RTEST/4.0.0-SNAPSHOT/ivy.xml",
                                              "md5":  "a242c427c6c1fdcd33c1c0498fb41324",
                                              "type":  "application/xml",
                                              "sha1":  "2d4916b9a1292dca8875b1aceaca9beb8de1a5e6"
                                          },
                                          {
                                              "name":  "/com/company/module/SPO3.MGUI.RTEST/4.0.0-SNAPSHOT/SPO3.MGUI.RTEST-bin-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip",
                                              "md5":  "581be6dd9e6615d14db2bb0d05c724e6",
                                              "type":  "application/x-gzip",
                                              "sha1":  "62436ab1aff6cdcdeba59bcac39d6223697398c4"
                                          }
                                      ]
                    }
                ]
```

"repo path" section under the artifactory builds page for my build shows this msg:
**"No path found (externally resolved or deleted/overwritten)"**
and this I believe because I am using incorrect payload while submitting the REST call.  **If I use correct information then this should be populated correctly and I can directly click on it to route to the artifact.**

Any help is appreciated here. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you have builds in the Build tab but all artifacts have "No path found (externally resolved or deleted/overwritten)" it most probably means that you did not add the needed properties to the uploaded files (build.name, build.number).

Comment: I have the properties updated in the artifact, still the same issue. Do you know what "module id" and "artifact name" to use when using the "build upload" REST endpoint?